# How to save html page code in sql database?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on sql server where i want to save html code into sql table.

when i am trying to save data it only take till first close statement and left are missing.

so how can i save all html at once.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to store the html in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
// Create DB connection
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("... connection string ...");

// Create command
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (htmlColumn) VALUES (@html)", connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@html", SqlDbType.VarChar);

// Execute command
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes and backslash have special meaning to SQL and are very likely to be present in an average html page. Make sure you store the page in an nvarchar which is long enough for the biggest page, or, if your pages are really big a CLOB.

You probably need to use some sort of EscapeQuotes routine.

Or use prepared statements for your insert/update.